# Vim visual mode text formatting

Tags: vim

I'm wonder if there is a way in vim to format text in visual mode.

Example:

```
 URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,matcher
 URxvt.url-launcher: /usr/bin/firefox
 URxvt.matcher.button: 1
```

To:

```
 URxvt.perl-ext-common :    default,matcher
 URxvt.url-launcher    :    /usr/bin/firefox
 URxvt.matcher.button  :    1
```

I'm new to using vim and would like to work on making my documents easily readable at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's "Align" plugin.
you can align your text on :

:align :

:help Align

^ once the plugin installed

Comment: I haven't looked into plugins too much yet, but after you mentioned it I found : https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align . Which seems to do the task. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use [Vim Awesome](http://vimawesome.com/?q=align) to find the align type plugin that fits your needs. I personally use [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular), but have heard good things about [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) as well.

Comment: Is worth mentioning that you should use a plugin manager if you want to keep your sanity :)